# Already using stderr, how do I detect if there was an error in a bash script

Tags: bash, stderr

I am backing small databases from several websites and sending the admin an email with the results.  I have already directed stderr to send the complete error in the email.   Is there a way I can detect whether an error occurred so that I can change the email subject to match?

I am using two files, the first just sets things up and is different in each site.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
#set -euo pipefail
set -u

email="admin@example.com"
keep="+14"

#include script
. cronjobs/do_backup.sh

echo Main
#mysql Config File
dbcfg="cronjobs/_dbaccess.cnf"

#Backup using database, group_suffix in cnf file and backup_name
db="zzzcity_directory"
dbgrp="_zzz_directory"
bkp="db_zzz_directory.sql"
backup $db $dbcfg $dbgrp $bkp &>>$msg

#Backup using database, group_suffix in cnf file and backup_name
db="zzzcity_potluck"
dbgrp="_zzz_potluck"
bkp="db_zzz_potluck.sql"
backup $db $dbcfg $dbgrp $bkp &>>$msg

#Maintain backup copies and send email
finalize $keep $email
echo Done
```

The second one is identical on every site.

**do_backup.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

timestamp=$(date +"%F")
backup_dir="backup"
mysqldump="/usr/bin/mysqldump"
stat="/usr/bin/stat"
msg="tmp/backup_msg"

echo "Date:     $(date)" > $msg
echo "Hostname: $(hostname)" >> $msg
echo >> $msg
echo >> $msg
mkdir -p "$backup_dir/$timestamp" 2>> $msg

main() {
  db=$1
  dbcfg=$2
  dbpgrp=$3
  bkp="$backup_dir/$timestamp/$4"
  echo "Backing:  $db"
  echo "To:       $bkp"
  $mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=$dbcfg --defaults-group-suffix=$dbgrp $db > $bkp
  size=$($stat -c%s $bkp)
  echo "Filesize: $size"
  echo
}

backup () {
  main $1 $2 $3 $4
}

finish () {
  keep=$1
  echo "Keeping:  $keep copies"
  echo "Removing excess backups"
  find $backup_dir/ -type d -mtime +$keep -exec rm -r {} +
  echo
  echo "Finished: $(date)"
}

finalize (){
  finish $1 &>>$msg
  mail  -s "MySQL Backup script has run" "$2" <$msg
  #rm -f $MSG
}
```

Further explanation

- It's run using cron, once a day at 2 am
- It's backing up MySQL databases with authentication in a `.cnf` file
- I am keeping 14 copies in directories whose names are the date of backup
- The oldest gets deleted

The email looks like this

> Date:     Tue May  9 02:00:02 AEST 2023
> Hostname: zzz
>
> Backing:  zzzcity_directory
> To:       backup/2023-05-09/db_zzz_directory.sql
> Filesize: 6463
>
> Backing:  zzzcity_potluck
> To:       backup/2023-05-09/db_zzz_potluck.sql
> Filesize: 3541
>
> Keeping:  +14 copies
> Removing excess backups
>
> Finished: Tue May  9 02:00:04 AEST 2023

---

**Question**
At the moment, the subject of the email is static.  I would like to change it if there is an error.  Otherwise, I have to open all the emails.  Since I have already used stderr to build up the details in the email, how do I obtain an indication that something has failed?  Two that come to mind are  mysqldump or filesystem errors.

Comment: What do you want to check for? If `mysqldump` ran correctly? Take a look at the return code, should be `0` if everything worked.

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify what the actual question is. Your title mentions detecting an error, so I guess you want to detect some sort of error? What error? What should happen? What does using stderr have to do with it?

Comment: @terdon - done.  I am not an expert at linux.  I thought stderr contains any errors in the commands. in this case from mysqldump and from backup script, which I have redirected to a file.

Comment: Side note: [quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618), unless you have a very, very good reason not to quote. Hardly any reason is good enough though.